# I am getting a syntax error on line 42(4th last line) and I cant fix it can someone please help?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    # This code reads in data.txt and loads it into an array
    # Array will be used to add friends, remove and list
    # when we quit, we'll overwrite original friends.txt with
    # contents 

    print"Welcome to the program"

    print "Enter the correct number"
    print "Hockey fan 1, basketball fan 2, cricket fan 3,Numbers of favorite players-4"
    choice = input("Select an option")

    while choice!=3:
        if choice==1:
            addString = raw_input("Who is your favorite player??")
            print "I love Kessel"
        elif choice==2:
            remInt = raw_input("Do you think that the Cavaliers will continue ther loosing ways?")
            print "I think they can beat the Clippers"
        else:
            inFile = open('data.txt','r')
                listNumbers = []
                for numbers in inFile:
                        listNumbers.append(numbers)
                        print numbers
                inFile.close()


    print "Cricket is a great sport"

def quit():
    Print "Quitting Goodbye!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The line that says Quitting goodbye

Answer (score 7):

If that's really your code, your `print` is upper-cased.

`print "Quitting Goodbye!"`

Also, I just ran your code, and you have some improper indentation in your `else` clause:

```
inFile = open('data.txt','r')
listNumbers = []
for numbers in inFile:
    listNumbers.append(numbers)
    print numbers
inFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

try lowercase "print"? {make answer at least 30 characters, please ignore}

Answer (score 1):

Look that you have written the print statement capitalized. It must be `print` not `Print`.